# Why the GameObject.animation does not have the play property?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Lift : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool pressedButton = false;
    private bool isElevatorUp = false;

    public GameObject target;

    void OnMouseOver()
    {
        pressedButton = true;
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        pressedButton = false;
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if(isElevatorUp == false)
        {
            target = GameObject.Find("Elevator");

        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if(pressedButton == true)
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(300, 300, 200, 20), "Press to use lift!");
        }
    }
}
```

When i type target.animation.
Then after the last point i see some properties but not play.

It should be: target.animation.Play but the Play is not exist.

Comment: actually GameObject.animation property has been deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct animation play function call on a GameObject such as `GameObject.PlayAnimation(...)` is now deprecated. 
You must use `GetComponent` to get the Animation component then call the `Play()` function afterwards.

```
target.GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
```

There is also Animator. If you are using the `Animator` instead of Animation:

```
target.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("animationState");
```